# Highcharts exporting: display only printbutton and export to png

Tags: highcharts

Good day,

i would like to display only the printbutton and the export/png button. 
has anyone an idea how to do this? I use the offline-exporting function

best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `exporting` parameter to customize the export options by setting the `contextButton`'s `menuItems` property as `buttons.slice(0,3)` to remove other options except 'Print Chart` and 'Download PNG Image' (See image below and demo fiddle URL is available below it).

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: buttons.slice(0,3)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/4uP5y/117/

Hope this helps!